# JS split() error in IE10 and below

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer, expression

The below function works fine on Chrome, FF and IE11. However I cant get it to work on IE 10. The split returns undefined when I try to split the returned string.

Here is my function:

```
var now = new Date(), timezoneOffset;

timezoneOffset = now.toString().split('GMT')[1];
timezoneOffset = timezoneOffset.split(' ')[0];
timezoneOffset = timezoneOffset.substr(0, 3) + ':' + timezoneOffset.substr(3, 2);

return timezoneOffset;
```

So the returned values are: (it could be different depending on your location)

1. now = Tue May 06 2014 15:31:03 GMT+0300 (EEST)
2. timezoneOffset (after first split) = +0300 (EEST)
3. timezoneOffset (after second split) = +0300
4. timezoneOffset (after substr and adding colon) = +03:00

On fiddle you can put an alert after `timezoneOffset = now.toString().split('GMT')[1];` to see the error on IE10

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gNB39/)

Comment: If the value returned by [`Date.prototype.toString()`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.2) was reliable, you could use `now.toString().match(/[+-]\d{4}/)[0]`, however the string isn't reliable so use Paul's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're making the false assumption that `now.toString()` contains `"GMT"`, let's see what is actually given (for me anyway) in IE;

```
"Tue May 6 13:48:08 UTC+0100 2014"
```

Notice no *GMT*, but a *UTC*.

This means `split_result[1]` is *undefined*, so `timezoneOffset` is *undefined* and hence your error

> `Unable to get property 'split' of undefined or null reference`

This isn't the best way to get the *timezone's offset* anyway, as we're already provided with a method for just that

```
date.getTimezoneOffset(); // offset in minutes i.e. for me it is -60
```

Now you can convert this number to your desired formatting;

```
var o = date.getTimezoneOffset();
var x = Math.abs(o),
    sign = (x === o ? '-' : '+' ),
    m = x % 60,
    h = (x - m) / 60;
m = (m < 10 ? '0' : '') + m;
h = (h < 10 ? '0' : '') + h;

return sign + h + ':' + m;
```

Comment: Why does it says Typeerror: date.getTimezoneOffset(); is not a function?

Comment: I added another var before date.getTimezoneOffset(); which is var a = new Date(); and then var o = a.getTimezoneOffset();. It works now